# The environment variable seems to have some problem- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

The image shows the error in VS code:

[image: error message - text below]

Text:

> The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing the '"' character. The existence of such a character is known to have caused the Python extension to not load. If the extension fails to load please modify your paths to remove this '"' character.
>
> Source: Python (Extension)

How can I resolve the error?
Also, there are no " in the path variable

Comment: Can you print the PATH variable? Perhaps `echo %PATH%` on the command line and `print(os.environ["PATH"])` in the python extension?

Comment: check all python folders or best fast solution is to uninstall, reinstall python first, and uninstall, reinstall vs code but carefully follow all requested tasks and recommended on-screen installation instructions.

Comment: @Shivam Sareen As tdelaney said, when we install other things similar to'node', there will be a situation where a semicolon is automatically generated, resulting in a connection, for example:'%NODE_HOME%\;%NODE_PATH%\'.
Solution: Delete the semicolons and write them on two lines separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WINDOWS 10]
I fixed the exact same problem a few minutes back.
I had an Environment variable as shown below

```
%PYTHON_HOME%\;%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts\
```

Steps to fix :

1. The above value should be split into 2 values
2. Remove `;`
3. Remove the trailing `\`from other python env variables

The values would look like:

```py
%PYTHON_HOME%

%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts
```

This fixed the issue for me.